# While reading txt file lines. I can't "append list" or "update dictionary" why?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**I have txt file like that:**

```
"aroint" : "Lorem.",
"agama" : "Simply.",
"allantoidea" : "Dummy.",
"ampelopsis" : "Whiske"\"red.",
"zopilote" : "Vulture.\n\n",
"zooedendrium" : "Infusoria."
```

**I tried to read the txt file, convert Python dictionary and then create the json file**

```
import json
dictionary = {}
with open('/Users/stackoverflowlover/Desktop/source.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        s = (line.replace("\"", "").replace("\n\n", "").replace("\n", "").strip().split(":"))
        xkey = (s[0])
        xvalue = (s[-1])
        zvalue = str(xvalue)
        value = zvalue[:0] + zvalue[0 + 1:]
        key = xkey.replace(' ', '', 1)
        dict = {'key1': 'stackoverflow'}
        dictadd={key:value}
        (dict.update(dictadd))
        dictionary_list = []
        dictionary_list.append(key)
        dictionary_list.append(value)
        
print(dictionary_list)
with open("/Users/stackoverflowlover/Desktop/test.json", 'w', encoding='utf8') as f3:
  json.dump(dict, f3, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
print(json.dumps(dict, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

**My output:**

```
['zooedendrium', 'Infusoria.']
{
    "key1": "stackoverflow",
    "zooedendrium": "Infusoria."
}
```

When I try to read lines I can see all of them, but after I can see just the last lines dictionary.
How I can fix that?

Comment: Seems like a lot of *copy* / *paste* code there, Try being more specific. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details.

Comment: I tried many different ways. I thought this useful to show other users. Ok next time I will post-minimal

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here ? you are trying to read two separate files (TXT,JSON) and create a dictionary for those ??

Comment: Try not the one being useful to others to be the next time..... and don't comment, but  get right on to it!

Comment: forget about im gonna delete

Comment: @sunilbaba  txt --->json I read txt I took all information over there I tried to create JSON dictionary

Comment: @CristiFati thank you for teach me. Good turn deserves the another please check modal-verbs request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. below logic will read you file and convert it to the JSON structure which you are looking as output

```
import re
import json

f = open("/Users/stackoverflowlover/Desktop/source.txt", "r")
data = {}

for line in f:
        line = line.split(":")
        line[0] = re.sub("[^\w]+", "", line[0])
        line[1] = re.sub("[^\w]+", "", line[1])
        data[line[0]] = line[1]
        
print(data)
```

Comment: Wow you're great how did you do that :) I'm gonna learn this method. @sunilbaba why I cant use list.append and dict.update do you have a any idea?

Comment: when data value "sentence(more than one word)" I got the error. I fixed that with your code. Thanks again. That's here:                                                                           
   `try:
        line = (line.replace("\"", "").replace("\n\n", "").replace("\n", "").strip().split(":"))
        line[0] = re.sub("[^\w]+", "", line[0])
        line[1] = re.sub("[^\w]+", " ", line[1])
        data[line[0]] = line[1]
    except:
        pass
data = {x:v[1:-1]for x, v in data.items()}`

Comment: Hope it helped you to resolve your issue :-)